# Enumerated class members undefined when in seperate file

Tags: c++, enums

Alright, I'm working with a group of students programming a game, using Visual Studio 2015.

I have an enum class defined in the files DataTypes.h and DataTypes.cpp, however when I try to use them an a third file, AiFSM.cpp, I recieve a generic compiler error:

"objectType has no member 'TYPE_ENEMY_SHIP'"

I get the same issue if I use enum instead of enum class, except the error throw is:

"Identifier 'TYPE_ENEMY_SHIP' is undefined."

However, When I include the definition of the enum in AiFSM.cpp, the code compiles. This gave me the impression my includes were the source of the error, but I've rechecked and then retyped them (just in case), to no avail.

Could anyone please suggest what's causing the problem, please?

DataTypes.h:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef DATATYPES_H  //Duel header guard to support other compilers
#define DATATYPES_H

enum class objectType;
```

DataTypes.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "DataTypes.h"

enum class objectType {
    ...(Long list of enums omitted)
    //NOW we have NPC classes
    TYPE_ENEMY_SHIP,
    TYPE_ENEMY_STATION,
    ...
    TYPE_DESTROYED
};
```

AiFSM.h:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef AIFSM_H
#define AIFSM_H

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "DataTypes.h"

void enterFSM(objectType* type, FSMData* fsmData);

#endif
```

And finally, AiFSM.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "DataTypes.h"
#include "AiFSM.h"

//Passes the data onto the appropriate state
void enterFSM(objectType* type, FSMData* fsmData) {
    switch (*type) {
         case objectType::TYPE_ENEMY_SHIP:
           {break;} //TODO: Implement code
         ...(More case statements with identical errors.)

    }
}
```

Comment: You should define your enum values in the header.

Comment: Is there any reason you use a forward declaration? It seems pretty useless here.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: I suppose I don't actually need to forward dec. it, but their are a pile of structs, classes, and pre-processor macros that do. It seemed logical to put the enum in with the rest of our data types, so we had central access to it.

Comment: @VeraFWC: Better put each type into its own *.h/*.cpp combination (or just into a *.h file if you don't need a *.cpp, as is the case with enum classes). Using forward declarations or not is the concern of the code which uses the type, not of the type itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the full enum class declaration to the DataTypes.h header file.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. Incidentally, Is that to suggest that enum classes only have file scope regardless of includes? Because we're using the same enum in a number of files, is their any solution what doesn't involve declaring the enum for each .cpp file? Thanks!

Comment: @VeraFWC You should include `DataTypes.h` where ever you need it after moving the value definitions.

Comment: This is one of the rather unpleasant limitations of the C++ language :( Yes, you do have to put the full `enum` definition into the header file. Just doing a forward declaration only lets the compiler know that such a type exists but doesn't let you use it.

Comment: Enums behave like constants. So that the declaration has to appear in every single source file (via included header).